# Help understanding a phrase from a video

Tags: american-english, phrases, listening

I'm trying to translate the video from Saturday Night Live and I can't catch a little phrase from 1:18 to 1:21.
Would you be so kind as to tell me what they say?

The video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfB3gFrbthM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and promote my comment to an answer because no-one else answered. The video in the question is not available in the US on YouTube, but you can find it on [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/watch/705075?cmp=878&cmc=2724).

Closed captioning doesn't make it clear but I think in this context it is a repetition or variation of "Paul and Phil". It might be "Paul con Phil" where "con" is being used as a joke to make their names like "chili con carne" which is understood by Americans even though it is a Spanish phrase. It's hard to be certain, because much of SNL's skits are improvised and sometimes the joke fails because it ends up being an ["inside joke"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/inside+joke). I don't think you're missing any humor of the skit if you don't know exactly what they're saying.